# Can we have RSS feeds of normal SharePoint Stack Exchange Users?

Tags: feature-request, rss

This may not be an important feature request but it definitely would be quite a handy feature to subscribe to a RSS of a particular SharePoint Stack Exchange user. For example, I can put a RSS feed to [my activity](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1874/falak-mahmood?tab=activity) on my personal blog. Moreover, my blog readers can also view my [recently answered questions/comments](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1874/falak-mahmood?tab=answers&sort=newest) resulting in more traffic to Stack Exchange network. Is this something worth considering at the moment, or do we have any existing feature fulfilling this request?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Maybe try and post this in SO, since the engine is the same.

Comment: but Anders, what do you think about the concept? Is it something worth considering at the moment?

Comment: I havent really considered it. As you present it it sounds like a good idea :-)

Comment: I've seen this asked about on other SE sites, you may want to ask on SO meta first, if they apply it there it can be applied globally to all SE sites that want it.

Comment: You find general discussion on SO-meta, at least [this][1] two [questions][2].


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18978/185025
  [2]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/185025